# Configure Oracle Virtual Machine on Azure

Tags: oracle, azure, cloud, virtual-machine

I'm trying to deploy an Oracle database on a virtual machine which is hosted on azure.
So far I have been following their documentation

`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/workloads/oracle/oracle-database-quick-create`

I did everything step by step as they say over there, but ultimately I can't connect to it no matter how much I try it says request time out.

Strange thing is that I am able to ssh into it, but I can't access the database. I would like to mention that according to their documentation I forwarded the ports as shown below. I got no clue why exactly is not working.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended value for the `source port ranges` is `*`, it means any. Inbound Port filtering is mainly used with the `destination port ranges`. It's the same configuration for port 1521,5502. You can change the `source port ranges` from a specific port to `*`

If it's still no luck, you need to verify if outbound traffic to these ports is allowed from your local machine or corporate company firewall. For example, run the PowerShell command on your local machine `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 13.92.x.x(VM pip) -Port 5502`

Also, you need to make sure the [database is startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/workloads/oracle/oracle-database-quick-create#automate-database-startup-and-shutdown) before you want to connect to it.

It works on my side by full following that [quick guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/workloads/oracle/oracle-database-quick-create).
[image]

NSG configuration

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the database, but I solved it by editing the listener.ora file.
Change "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))" to "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))".
[image]

Don't forget to restart the server.